Timeout Issue with ‘/cameras/list’ Service in ROS Baxter Simulation on Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04
I am a student currently working with the Baxter robot in a ROS simulation environment. I'm encountering an issue with the robot's camera where the system reports a timeout when waiting for the /cameras/list service. This error occurs on both Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 operating systems.
I have tried running the camera_control.py script, but I encountered the following error messages:
dyj2@dyj2-name:~/ros_ws$ rosrun baxter_tools camera_control.py -l
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dyj2/ros_ws/src/baxter_tools/scripts/camera_control.py", line 159, in <module> sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/dyj2/ros_ws/src/baxter_tools/scripts/camera_control.py", line 155, in main  action(camera, res)
  File "/home/dyj2/ros_ws/src/baxter_tools/scripts/camera_control.py", line 47, in list_cameras rospy.wait_for_service('cameras/list', timeout=10)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 143, in wait_for_service
    raise ROSException("timeout exceeded while waiting for service %s"%resolved_name) rospy.exceptions.ROSException: timeout exceeded while waiting for service /cameras/list
dyj2@dyj2-name:~/ros_ws$  rosrun baxter_tools camera_control.py -c right_hand_camera
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dyj2/ros_ws/src/baxter_tools/scripts/camera_control.py", line 159, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/dyj2/ros_ws/src/baxter_tools/scripts/camera_control.py", line 155, in main action(camera, res)
  File "/home/dyj2/ros_ws/src/baxter_tools/scripts/camera_control.py", line 94, in close_camera
    cam = CameraController(camera)
  File "/home/dyj2/ros_ws/src/baxter_interface/src/baxter_interface/camera.py", line 77, in __init__  rospy.wait_for_service('/cameras/list', timeout=10)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 143, in wait_for_service  raise ROSException("timeout exceeded while waiting for service %s"%resolved_name)
rospy.exceptions.ROSException: timeout exceeded while waiting for service /cameras/list

Below is a portion of the camera_control.py file:
import errno

import rospy

from baxter_core_msgs.msg import (
    CameraControl,
    CameraSettings,
)

from baxter_core_msgs.srv import (
    CloseCamera,
    ListCameras,
    OpenCamera,
)


class CameraController(object):
    """
    Interface class for controlling camera settings on the Baxter robot.
    """

    # Valid resolutions
    MODES = [
             (1280, 800),
             (960, 600),
             (640, 400),
             (480, 300),
             (384, 240),
             (320, 200),
             ]

    # Used to represent when the camera is using automatic controls.
    # Valid for exposure, gain and white balance.
    CONTROL_AUTO = -1

    def __init__(self, name):
        """
        Constructor.

        @param name: camera identifier.  You can get a list of valid
                     identifiers by calling the ROS service /cameras/list.

                     Expected names are right_hand_camera, left_hand_camera
                     and head_camera.  However if the cameras are not
                     identified via the parameter server, they are simply
                     indexed starting at 0.
        """
        self._id = name

        list_svc = rospy.ServiceProxy('/cameras/list', ListCameras)
        rospy.wait_for_service('/cameras/list', timeout=10)
        if not self._id in list_svc().cameras:
            raise AttributeError(
                ("Cannot locate a service for camera name '{0}'. "
                "Close a different camera first and try again.".format(self._id)))

Could you please suggest a solution or provide guidance on how to resolve the timeout issue with the /cameras/list service?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
